# How do you return a list of the current project folders and files of your current project in QtCreator?

Tags: application-development, programming, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

I think Qt must have this, because QtCreator has a list on its sidebar:

[image]

Ideally I am just looking for a Qt function that will just return this list.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you'll be better off telling us what you're *actually* trying to do.  You won't be shipping your sources to your users, so there's no call to list the project's files in your program.  Are you trying to build a Qt Creator plugin?  Are you trying to list files in an arbitrary directory?  (I suspect that Qt Creator has custom code to parse your qmake or cmake files and figure out which files to show.)

Comment: @RobertSchroll Yes; this is for a qtcreator plugin. In short; I am looking for a way to locate a folder in a project called "tests". From that; I want to create a UI that will run tests from QtCreator.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the files in a given directory with [QDir::entryList()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList).  `QDir` has a number of other methods that may be useful for you as well.